# checkbox submittion to mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, html, forms, checkbox

i am trying to create a checkbox system to complete an online form i have.

Everything about the form works fine except the checkbox section. It just posts nothing to the database.

```
     <input type='checkbox' name='species' value='$txt' />$txt<br/>
```

The code above of placed into the form page and it dynamically pulls info from databse to display the full list of species. This pasrt also works fine and it displays them all on the form as expected. However when the user ticks any or all of the checkboxs then nothing is posted to the database on submission of the form. Everything else from the form is submitted though. No errors come back from the database.

```
    $_POST[species]
```

Can anyone suggested what could be going wrong here?

Secondly the form is about fishing. A user could select a few speices (e.g Brown trout, Rainbow trout & golden trout) Is it possible to post this as Brown, Golden & Rainbow Trout?? I assume it is possible would require alot of IF statements??? Is this the only way because it seems like a very long route with alot of combinations...

Any help on these two questions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using PHP to handle forms is pretty well documented online. [Try this article over at PHP Freaks](http://www.phpfreaks.com/tutorial/working-with-checkboxes-and-a-database).

Looks like you're looking for

```
<input type='checkbox' name='species[]' value='$txt' />$txt<br/>
```